# Warm Up script JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've found a script and made a number of changes, including placing inside HTML to run the script via a webpage. From within the webpage how do I run the script without the use of a prompt etc. I'm sure I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Volume</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Warmup Script</h1>
<script>

function warmup() {
    warmUpSite("http://TestWebSite.com");
}

function warmUpSite(url) {
    console.info("warming up: " + url);

    var req = require('request');
    req.get({ url: url }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error) {
            alert("hot hot hot! " + url);
        } else {
            alert('error warming up ' + url + ': ' + error);
        }
    });
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well you are not calling your function. Somewhere you should have a `warmup()` call.

Answer (score 2):

Add a call to the `warmup()` function at the bottom of your script:

```
warmup();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried that but still simply get a webpage with "Warmup Script", but no alerts. Is there anywhere (console etc) where I can run this to get feedback on errors.

Comment: Chrome and IE have a Developer Mode if you press F12. There's a console, to which you can write with `console.log()`.

Comment: Thanks Mark - Exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

Invoke your `warmup` function like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Volume</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Warmup Script</h1>
<script>

function warmup() {
    warmUpSite("http://TestWebSite.com");
}

function warmUpSite(url) {
    console.info("warming up: " + url);

    var req = require('request');
    req.get({ url: url }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error) {
            alert("hot hot hot! " + url);
        } else {
            alert('error warming up ' + url + ': ' + error);
        }
    });
}

// invoke function
warmup();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It looks like you are trying trying to load a module with your `require` call. If you run this code you will see in your console (hit F12 in Chrome): `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

This is because the `require` function is not built-in to JavaScript. You need to load a library for that.

Perhaps you are trying to use [require.js](http://requirejs.org/)?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I used http://jsconsole.com and found that require is not defined, I'll take a look at the link otherwise I'll see if I can find another way around the issue.